# postinst is not called, but preinst

Tags: linux, busybox, opkg

I am on Busybox and create my own packages. I have preinst and postinst files, preinst is called when I install the package, but postinst is not. The read and execute permissions are corretly set. I don't get an error message when I create or install the package. I inserted echo instructions into the files and I tripped the files to a minimum, but I only get the answers from preinst. Any ideas?

preinst:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "in preinst"

exit 0
```

postinst:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "in postinst"

exit 0
```

Comment: Maybe you start with a [mcve]? Also, are there no working examples on the internet?

Comment: But it's hardly possible to make it as minimal as an echo statement, is it? The installation itself works perfectly, apart from the postinst.

Comment: It's not so much about reducing your code here further (the `exit 0` is redundant though), it's about making it reproducible! I don't know what you did, so I can't reproduce it. Don't require interpretation of what you did! Also, please check out the descriptions of the tags that you apply.

Comment: In fact, I stripped the code and it worked. I'll rebuild the code and see what happens. Thank you anyway